# WebSocket Disconnection Issue When Writing to Files Ending in '.json' in Node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket

In Node.js, a websocket server is created using the 'ws' library, and when a 'message' event is received, the data is written to 'mydata.json' using 'fs.writeFile'. However, in practice, whenever a file with a '.json' extension is written, it causes the websocket server to disconnect, even though the data is successfully written to the file. If the file extension is changed to something else (e.g., '*.log'), this issue does not occur.

What could be causing this problem, and how can it be resolved?

```
// package.json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "ws": "^8.13.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nodemon src/server.js"
    }
}
```

```
// server.js

const fs = require("fs");
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
  console.log("Client connected.");

  ws.on("message", async (message) => {
    try {
      const jsonData = JSON.parse(message);
      await writeToJSONFile(jsonData);
      console.log("Data written to file successfully.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error handling JSON data:", error);
    }
  });

  ws.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected.");
  });
});

async function writeToJSONFile(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile("mydata.json", JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

On a side note, I have tried running two different servers on the localhost using Node.js, where one server receives HTTP requests and writes to '.json' using 'fs.writeFile', while the other server handles WebSocket tasks without involving 'fs.writeFile'. Surprisingly, even when I attempt to send an HTTP request to write to '.json', the WebSocket still gets disconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to Mehriddin Nozimov's response, I learned about the mechanism to trigger nodemon to restart the server. Therefore, I added nodemon.json to exclude files/directories that do not need to be monitored.

```
// nodemon.json

{
  ignore: ["mydata.json"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, nodemon also listens to json files, I think when the json file is overwritten, nodemon restarts the server and deletes previous connections

to solve this

```
nodemon --ignore '*.json' src/server.js
```

Comment: Although the problem was not resolved, it turns out that it was caused by nodemon's updated hot reload feature. I now have a good research direction, thanks.